# Find possible outcomes with limits in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I need to collect data from the user that will consist of a number of variables and each variable will have a value. I need to find the possible combinations based on the values not exceeding a certain limit. Also each variable belongs to a group and cannot be repeated. So for example to user inputs:

```
GROUP1: (A,B,C) with values (5,6,4)
GROUP2: (A,B,C,D) with values (4,3,6,3)
GROUP3: (A,B,C,D,E) with values (6,7,6,4,5)
```

These inputs are all gathered in a form and I can gather them no problem. What I need help with is the Math and Algorithm to output the possible combinations.

The Output must be formatted where the combinations consist of a set number from each group and the sum values of those numbers must not exceed 30.

```
Group1 has 1 index
Group2 has 2 indexes
Group3 has 3 indexes
```

The output should look something like this:

> Group 1: A   Group 2: A,C   Group 3: B,D,E

and any other possible combination that work fit. All the combinations will then be printed. It seems easy but yet seems complicated at the same time. Any help would be appreciated. I am doing this in Java. Thanks.

Comment: "Group1 has 1 index Group2 has 2 indexes Group3 has 3 indexes" What does this part mean? Maybe you can edit your example with an actual true result? As far as I understand all combinations of your given numbers are below 30, right?

Comment: Yes. i just need to make all possible combinations that are less than 30.

Comment: An actual real life example would be say I had to pick 1 meat, 2 fruits, and 3 vegetables from a group of food products. There total value has to be under $30. There are multiple meats in an array, multiple fruits in another array, and multiple vegetables in another array. I need to display all the possible outcomes that match the criteria of having 1 meat, 2 fruits, and 3 vegetables while still being under $30